# Python complex numbers notation

Tags: python

[Complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) use "i" to denote the [imaginary unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

Does anyone know, why [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) uses "j" instead?

Comment: Not only Python. I've seen other notations (even in books) that prefer italicized *j* to bolded **i**.

Comment: Electrical engineering uses [j for imaginary units](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/04/23/why-j-for-imaginary-unit/) too. Matlab support both `i` and `j`.

Comment: Did you read the Imaginary Unit wiki page which you've specifically linked to in the question?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes. How does it specifically relate to Python?

Answer (score 2):

> In some disciplines, in
>   particular electromagnetism and electrical engineering, j is used
>   instead of i, since i is frequently used for electric current. In
>   these cases complex numbers are written as a + bj or a + jb.

[Source.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Notation)

Answer (score 1):

The python complex number standard follows the *Engineering* standard where a `j` is used instead of an `i` to represent the square root of 1.

Also, check [this resource](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/04/23/why-j-for-imaginary-unit/) for an alternate explanantion.

It states that `j` is preferred when referring to complex numbers due to `i`'s multiple other uses which might lead to confusion.

Comment: We *don't know this*. Don't just copy my findings from the comments and present them as if Python follows that standard deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols **i**, **j**, and **k** are used for unit vectors in the directions of the x, y, and z axes respectively. That means that “i” has two different meanings in the real plane, depending on whether you think of it as the vector space spanned by i and j or as complex numbers. But if you use j to represent the imaginary unit, its meaning does not change. Either way it points along the y axis.

Said another way, bold face i and italic i point in different directions But bold face j and italic j both point in the same direction.

Source: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/04/23/why-j-for-imaginary-unit/

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers are a.o. heavily used in electronics for phase computations. An i denotes current there.